# Adding drop down menu to Choropleth map to select each state and generate new graph type

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I've created a Choropleth map and I want to know if it's possible to add a drop down with each state. When you select the drop down the graph changes to a line graph of the number of Bachelor degrees earned over time in that state.

A sample of my data:

```
        year state statetotal ba_total
0     1984.0    AK      221.0    108.0
1     1985.0    AK      242.0    141.0
2     1984.0    NC      229.0    117.0
3     1985.0    NC      257.0    138.0
4     1984.0    MA      272.0    165.0
5     1985.0    MA      280.0    176.0
6     1984.0    NY      375.0    249.0
7     1985.0    NY      309.0    208.0
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(str)

scl = [[0.0, 'rgb(242,240,247)'],[0.2, 'rgb(218,218,235)'],[0.4, 'rgb(188,189,220)'],\
            [0.6, 'rgb(158,154,200)'],[0.8, 'rgb(117,107,177)'],[1.0, 'rgb(84,39,143)']]

df['text'] = df['statename'] + '<br>' + \
    'Bachelor '+df['ba_total']+'<br>'+ \
    'Master '+df['ma_total']+'<br>'+ \
    'PhD '+df['phd_total']

# Years
years = list(df['year'].astype(float).astype(int).unique())

# make data
data = []

# Append data
for year in years:
    dataset_by_year = df[df['year'].astype(float).astype(int) == int(year)]

    data_dict = [ dict(
        type='choropleth',
        visible=True,
        colorscale = scl,
        autocolorscale = False,
        locations = dataset_by_year['state'],
        z = dataset_by_year['statetotal'].astype(float),
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        text = dataset_by_year['text'],
        marker = dict(
            line = dict (
                color = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                width = 2
            ) ),
        colorbar = dict(
            title = "Educ. Grads")
        ) ]
    data.append(data_dict[0])

# let's create the steps for the slider
steps = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    step = dict(method='restyle',
                args=['visible', [False] * len(data)],
                label='{}'.format(i + 1984))
    step['args'][1][i] = True
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(active=0,
                pad={"t": 1},
                steps=steps)]    

# create the empty dropdown menu
updatemenus = list([dict(buttons=list()), 
                    dict(direction='down',
                         showactive=True)])

total_codes = len(df.state.unique()) + 1

for s, state in enumerate(df.state.unique()):
    # add a trace for each state
    data.append(dict(type='scatter',
                     x=[i for i in range(1984, 2016)],
                     y=[i for i in df.statetotal],
                     visible=False))

    # add each state to the dropdown    
    visible_traces = [False] * total_codes
    visible_traces[s + 1] = True
    updatemenus[0]['buttons'].append(dict(args=[{'visible': visible_traces}],
                                          label=state,
                                          method='update'))

# add a dropdown entry to reset the map    
updatemenus[0]['buttons'].append(dict(args=[{'visible': [True] + [False] *  (total_codes - 1)}],
                                      label='Map',
                                      method='update'))

layout = dict(title='Aggregated Number of Graduates in Education by State',
              updatemenus=updatemenus,
              geo=dict(scope='usa',
                       projection={'type': 'albers usa'}),
              sliders=sliders)

fig = dict(data=data, 
           layout=layout)
```

I'm getting an `AttributeError` related to the function I've created but previously I managed to generate the graph with the menus present but the graph generated 50 menu buttons rather than a drop down with 50 options.

I think these issues can be resolved but the crux of my problems are whether or not it's possible to combine graph types together? Ideally I'd want to show a line graph if I click on Alaska showing the number of bachelor's degrees completed over the time period observed. 
Is this possible?

**EDIT Code**

I managed to get the drop down menu to work but it doesn't mesh well with the [slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777047/how-to-make-a-choropleth-map-with-a-slider-using-plotly) and the map. I don't know how to get slider to disappear when you click an item in the drop down menu or how to prevent the map from being overlayed on top of the line graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the desired functionality with Plotly online but all the data needs to be loaded when the first graph is rendered. Perhaps have a look at Plotly's Dash which enabled dynamic loading of data.

In order to get the dropmenu which shows traces you could do the following:

- First create map, then add a scatter plot for each country but only show the map by setting the `visible` attribute.
- Create a [drop down menu](https://plot.ly/python/dropdowns/#update-dropdown) which shows the scatter plot for the selected country (by passing an array of Booleans to `visible`)
- Add a menu entry to show the map again

---

[image]

### [image]

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv')

# create the initial map
data = [dict(type='choropleth',
             locations = df['code'].astype(str),
             z=df['total exports'].astype(float),
             locationmode='USA-states', 
             visible=True)]

layout = dict(geo=dict(scope='usa',
                       projection={'type': 'albers usa'}))

# create the empty dropdown menu
updatemenus = list([dict(buttons=list()), 
                    dict(direction='down',
                         showactive=True)])

total_codes = len(df.code.unique()) + 1

for s, state in enumerate(df.code.unique()):
    # add a trace for each state
    data.append(dict(type='scatter',
                     x=[i for i in range(1980, 2016)],
                     y=[i + random.random() * 100 for i in range(1980, 2016)],
                     visible=False))

    # add each state to the dropdown    
    visible_traces = [False] * total_codes
    visible_traces[s + 1] = True
    updatemenus[0]['buttons'].append(dict(args=[{'visible': visible_traces}],
                                          label=state,
                                          method='update'))

# add a dropdown entry to reset the map    
updatemenus[0]['buttons'].append(dict(args=[{'visible': [True] + [False] *  (total_codes - 1)}],
                                      label='Map',
                                      method='update'))
layout['updatemenus'] = updatemenus

fig = dict(data=data, 
           layout=layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: This is amazing! Do you if you can combine this with the slider, so the slider only shows up with the map? (see edit)

Comment: @otteheng: Probably yes, you would need to update the `layout` for each dropdown menu as well, it probably gets a bit messy but it should work.

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble knowing where to look in `layout` to turn off `slider`. I can disable `slider` for the entire graph but not for each drop down individually.

Comment: I was showing this code to a colleague so they could reproduce this with another data set but it doesn't seem to work as intended anymore. A quick glance makes me think this has something to do with what items are visible or not. Will look more closely later.