# Python Plotly: Using dropdown menu to switch between choropleth map and scatterplot

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

I am new to using plotly and I am attempting to build a dynamic visualisation using python and plotly. I hope to be able to switch between a world choropleth map and a scatter plot using a drop-down menu.

So far I have been able to successfully get a dropdown menu to appear and show the required labels and even show a single plot by removing either the choropleth map or scatter plot trace from the data variable. The problem is that I when I try to have both plots implemented the choropleth map is drawn over the top of the scatterplot regardless of the menu option I choose.

A [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbsHo.jpg) of the output.

## Areas I Have Looked For A Solution

The [plotly reference](https://community.plot.ly/) and looked through the updatemenus and layout sections among many others.

Reviewed the ploty python [tutorial page for dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46818391/adding-drop-down-menu-to-choropleth-map-to-select-each-state-and-generate-new-gr) and implementing parts of the suggestion in my code with a focus on the update method.

I have found a [StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46818391/adding-drop-down-menu-to-choropleth-map-to-select-each-state-and-generate-new-gr) that seemed to be very close to the answer I needed however not quite.

Finally, I also searched the [plotly community forum](https://community.plot.ly/).

## The Code

Note I have removed a portion of the code such as imports and data at the beginning.

```
scatterplot = go.Scatter(

    y = df2['Renewable energy consumption (% of total final energy consumption) 2015'],
    x = df2['GDP per capita, PPP (constant 2011 international $) 2015'],
    mode='markers',
    ids=df2['Country Name'],
    showlegend = False,
      marker = dict(
          size = 8,
          color = np.random.randn(500),
        ),
      textfont = dict(
        size = 14,
        color = 'black')
)

choropleth_map = dict(
        type = 'choropleth',
        locations = df['ISO3166_alpha3'],
        z = df['renewables_mtoe'],
        text = df['Country'],
        colorscale = [[0,"rgb(106, 240, 255)"],[0.10,"rgb(106, 199, 255)"],[0.70,"rgb(50, 100, 255)"],[0.93,"rgb(0, 43, 198)"],\
          [0.99999,"rgb(0, 24, 109)"],[1,"rgb(220, 220, 220)"]],
        autocolorscale = False,
        reversescale = True,
        marker = dict(
            line = dict (
                color = 'rgb(180,180,180)',
                width = 0.5
            ) ),
        colorbar = dict(
            title = 'mtoe<br>',
            tickfont = dict(
                size = 16),
            titlefont = dict(
                size = 16)),
)

data = [choropleth_map, scatterplot]

updatemenus = list([
    dict(active=0,
         buttons=list([   
            dict(label = 'choropleth_map',
                 method = 'update',
                 args = [{'visible': [True,False]},
                         {'title': 'The Map'}]),
            dict(label = 'scatterplot',
                 method = 'update',
                 args = [{'visible': [False,True]},
                         {'title': 'Scatterplot'}]),
        ]),       
    )
])

layout = dict(title='default', showlegend=False,
                  updatemenus=updatemenus,
        geo = dict(showframe = True,
                    showcoastlines = False,
                    showland = True,
                    landcolor = '#dcdcdc',
                    projection = dict(type = 'natural earth'))
)

fig = dict( data=data, layout=layout )
plotly.offline.iplot(fig, validate=True)
```

A big thank you in advance to anyone who can help. I have spent days trying to solve this problem, it has even driven me to make my first post on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi @fname, could you please simplify your question and post just the problem you're facing, posting if possible just the code that gives the problem? This question is way too long and many details are actually not useful. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @toti08, thanks for the advice, I have shortened my question. I included where I searched for a solution according to StackOverflow post recommendations, but happy to remove/edit those too if it is too verbose. If there is anything else I can clarify please let me know.